# Android Socket Programming Using Binder Over Ethernet

Tags: android, kotlin, sockets, ethernet, android-binder

I've been trying to find examples of people creating a socket between two android devices through the use of a binder (service) over an ethernet connection. I can't really seem to find any examples or really any information through Android Open Source. If anyone could help me get started or if you recommend any examples that would be greatly appreciated. I primarily use kotlin but will also use java. Thank you!

Tried looking for builds on Github or information on Android Open Source but really couldn't find anything. Need specifically binder over ethernet using a socket between two android devices.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Binder framework is an inter-process communication framework. Processes communicate using file descriptors, ioctls and shared memory if I remember correctly.

Binder doesn't support communicating over the ethernet. It was designed to satisfy entirely different set of requirements, and was implemented on top of different set of technologies.